# Admin forgot password does not work with X-Content-Type-Options nosniff header

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx

When using nginx with X-Content-Type-Options nosniff, e.g:

```
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

With location specific rewrite in server block:

```
location = /js/index.php/x.js {
        rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

Chrome console reveals the following:

```
Refused to execute script from 'http://www.{YOURDOMAIN}.com/js/index.php/x.js?f=prototype/prototype.js,prototy…s,mage/adminhtml/events.js,mage/adminhtml/form.js,scriptaculous/effects.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
captcha.js:25 Uncaught ReferenceError: Class is not defined(anonymous function) @ captcha.js:25
(index):42 Uncaught ReferenceError: varienForm is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look inside `js/index.php` line 45:

```
// allow web server set content type automatically
$contentType = false;
```

probably changing it to `true`will help you to set correct content type.

```
location = /js/index.php/x.js {
       rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and looking into this with me. My .conf file already has that location block in it near the end. You are correct in that changing the `$contentType = false;` does solve the "Refused to execute script...". However it does not solve the remaining Uncaught ReferenceErrors, and the form is still broken.

Comment: form works fine, you need to check your specific changes....

Comment: You are correct. The lines in the conf file were commented out, just removed comment out and restarted nginx and works perfect. Thanks ^_^!!

Comment: Changing the $contentType to true worked for me. This must be necessary when using nginx to serve magento 1.9