# Admin Forget Password not working? nothing happen when click on button

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-panel, password-recovery, change-password

i try to inspect what happen 
[image]

its show validation.js.. many more javascript file missing but they are in right place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Admin forgot password does not work with X-Content-Type-Options nosniff header](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125453/admin-forgot-password-does-not-work-with-x-content-type-options-nosniff-header)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in certain versions of Magento.

Try overriding the below template. Then remove the onclick and change the button type to a submit (code is below):

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/forgotpassword.phtml**

change

```
<button class="forgot-password" onclick="loginForm.submit()" type="button"><span><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Retrieve Password'); ?></span></span></span></button>
```

to

```
<button class="forgot-password" type="submit"><span><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Retrieve Password'); ?></span></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nginx, add this to your config file:

```
location = /js/index.php/x.js {
   rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
}
```